# Scrape Intranet site without a web server

Tags: web-development, web-scraping

I'm trying to rebuild a simple c# time tool that displays certain statistics about time worked for the web, however, I don't have access to a server so I can't use server code like PHP which I would do if I could and this task would be a doddle.

The employee's work information is stored on an intranet site that the C# tool could access by scraping that site and grabbing what it needed. How can I do this (scrape the intranet site) without using server code and only client-side things like HTML, JavaScrit/jQuery?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention the Windows machines don't have .net installed

Comment: This might be useful for you: (net-equivalent-of-htmlunit)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463735/net-equivalent-of-htmlunit]

Comment: How are you building a C# tool for machines that don't have .NET installed?

Comment: Long story short, there's a department at the site that have windows machines with no .NET, the decision of app platform change is for them.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a server isn't really an issue for C#, lack of the .net framework is.  You don't need a webserver to interact with one.

Absence of the framework is insurmountable absent a truly heroic effort (write your own compiler and linker and probably framework as well).

Your choice basically boils down to: native app (probably done in c++), install the .net framework, install the java framework.   Or more realistically in an intranet, get a server of some sort (terminal server or webserver).

That's the best you can do with your current architecture -- but I question it.  If this is on an intranet, why not directly access the resources that the sites use in order to present the data in another format, or add another page that presents the data in the way you want.